# Table Collapse js

Tags: javascript, tabs, twitter-bootstrap

I want my table collapsing in an other table as default.

Here in the example below the table are collapsed but as default the page shows both the Table, i want one page shown and one hidden that can be visible clicking over the icon down.

Hope the explanation is clear

Thanks

This is the case: http://jsfiddle.net/gianlucaguarini/hAv7P/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.accordion').on('show hide', function(e){
    $(this).find('.accordion-toggle i').toggleClass('icon-arrow-down icon-arrow-up', 200);
});

$('.accordion-body').collapse();​  // note the class
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hAv7P/5/